# Integration of a function which behavior is comparable with the function $\sin$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am struggling with the following problem: Let $$\frac{\pi_p}{2}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1-s^p)^{1/p}}ds$$

where $p\in (1,\infty)$. Define $\operatorname{sin_p}:[0,\pi_p/2]\to [0,1]$ by $$x=\int_0^{\operatorname{sin_p}(x)}\frac{1}{(1-s^p)^{1/p}}ds$$

Note that $$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{sin_p}(x)\right)^p=1-(\operatorname{sin_p}(x))^p$$

Define $\frac{d}{dx}\operatorname{sin_p}(x)=\operatorname{cos_p}(x)$. I am trying to prove that $$\frac{4(2\pi_p)^{-1}}{p^{-1}}\int_0^{\pi_p/2}(\operatorname{sin_p}(x))^pdx=1$$

If $p=2$ we have the usual $\sin $ function and for this function, the tecnique that I use to solve the last integral is to consider the relation $\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$. I tried to prove a analogous fact for the case $p\neq 2$, but then I discovered that the derivative of $\operatorname{cos_p}(x)$ is not a multiple of $\sin_p(x)$. Now I am stuck.

Update: If we do the change of variables $x=\operatorname{arcsin_p}(y^{1/p})$ where $\operatorname{arcsin_p}$ is the inverse of $\operatorname{sin_p}$ then we get $$\int_0^{\pi_p/2}(\sin_p(x))^p dx=\frac{1}{p}\int_0^1 \frac{y^{1/p}}{(1-y)^{1/p}}dy$$

Mathematica returns the desired result, however, how can I integrate it by hand?

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we use our good friend, the Beta function, we get

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\pi_p}{2} &= \int_0^1 (1-s^p)^{-1/p}\,ds \tag{substitute $t = s^p$}\\
&= \frac1p \int_0^1 t^{1/p-1}(1-t)^{-1/p}\,dt\\
&= \frac1p B\left(\frac1p, 1-\frac1p\right)\\
&= \frac1p \Gamma\left(\frac1p\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac1p\right)\tag{since $\Gamma(1) = 1$}\\
&= \frac{\pi/p}{\sin (\pi/p)} \tag{since $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}$}.
\end{align}$$

And supposing your $\arcsin_p$ subsitution is correct (I haven't checked), we get

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\pi_p/2} (\sin_p x)^p\,dx &= \frac1p \int_0^1 y^{1/p} (1-y)^{-1/p}\,dy\\
&= \frac1p B\left(1+\frac1p, 1-\frac1p\right)\\
&= \frac1p \Gamma\left(1+\frac1p\right)\Gamma\left(1-\frac1p\right)\tag{since $\Gamma(2) = 1$}\\
&= \frac{\pi/p^2}{\sin (\pi/p)}\\
&= \frac1p\frac{\pi_p}{2}.
\end{align}$$

So we have indeed

$$\frac{4(2\pi_p)^{-1}}{p^{-1}}\int_0^{\pi_p/2}(\operatorname{sin_p}(x))^p\,dx=1$$

as desired.

Comment: Yes you are right, there is a typo there. Thank for your answer, I think I have to learn something about the Beta and Gamma functions. Every integral that I cannot answer and I post here, people use these functions to solve it...

Comment: Yes, these two are _amazingly_ useful. Not quite as universal as the exponential or the trigonometric functions, but they turn up a lot.